# View more button with count if more than 2 in react map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, javascript-objects

I have a set of object .

```
var set2 = {
      men: { value: "men", label: "Men", type: "select", "options": [{label: "Tshirt", value_string: "1"}, {label: "Shirt", value_string: "2"}, {label: "Shoes", value_string: "6"}, {label: "Pants", value_string: "7"}] },
}
```

Inside option set i have few set of label Like Tshirt,Shirt,Shoes etc.

So if option has more than 2 set,I want to show View more button and inside button i want to show the remaining count . Example - I have 4 set inside option. I want to show first two and the remaining count and + symbol. Example i want to render like this `Men -`  `Tshirt  Shirt`   **2+** . One click of 2+ it will show all remaining .

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```js
const SHOW_BY_DEFAULT = 2;
export default function App() {
  const [showAll, setShowAll] = useState(false);
  const options = set2.men.options;
  const visibleOptions = showAll ? options.length : SHOW_BY_DEFAULT;
  const toggleShowAll = () => {
    setShowAll(!showAll);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      {options.slice(0, visibleOptions).map(({ label }) => (
        <div>{label}</div>
      ))}
      {options.length > SHOW_BY_DEFAULT && (
        <div onClick={toggleShowAll}>
          {!showAll ? `+${options.length - SHOW_BY_DEFAULT} more` : "Show Less"}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const Button = () => {
  const DEFAULT_LABELS = 2
  const [showLables, setShowLables] = useState('showTwoLabels')
  const set2 = {
    men: {
      value: "men", label: "Men", type: "select", "options": [{
        label: "Tshirt",
        value_string: "1"
      }, { label: "Shirt", value_string: "2" }, {
        label: "Shoes",
        value_string: "6"
      }, { label: "Pants", value_string: "7" }]
    },
  }
  return (
    <div>
      {set2.men.options.length <= DEFAULT_LABELS  ? set2.men.options.map(rec => {
        return <span>{rec.label}</span>
      }) : <div>
          {showLables === 'showTwoLabels' ? <span>{set2.men.options[0].label}, {set2.men.options[0].label}</span> : false}
          {showLables === 'showTwoLabels' ? <button type="button" onClick={() => setShowLables('ShowAllLabels')}>+{set2.men.options.length - DEFAULT_LABELS}</button> : false}
          {showLables === 'ShowAllLabels' ? <span>{set2.men.options.map(rec => <span>{rec.label} </span>)}</span> : false}
        </div>}
    </div>)
}
```